Invertibility of a linear transformation.

Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to  $\Bbb R^n$.Let {${x_1,x_2,....,x_n}$} be a basis of $\Bbb R^n$ s.t. $x_i\perp N(T)$ $\forall i$, then to show $T$ is invertible.

My attempt:
Let $x\in N(T)$.Then $x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i{x_i}$,for some $\alpha_i\in\Bbb R$.
Now as,  $x_j\perp N(T)$ $\forall j$ $\implies $$<x,x_j>=0$ $\forall j$.
$\implies <\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i{x_i},x_j>=0 \forall j$.
Now from here if i am able to show that $\alpha_i{=}0$ $\forall i$ then T is invertible.I do'nt have idea how to proceed from here.Kindly help me.

Hint: If a vector is orthogonal to all basis elements then it is orthogonal to the whole space.

@Mark ok .so you want to say that every vector in null space of T is orthogonal to whole space and hence every element of N(T) is orthogonal to itself and  0 is the only vector with this property so N(T)={0}.

@Mark I want to prove this step by step.Can you share a proof?Thank you.

Just to add more tips: for $T$ to be invertible, its determinant musn't be zero.

@SandeepTiwari You already wrote the whole idea, now just write the details. I'm sure you can do it.

@Mark Sir, i want to show $\alpha_i=0$ $\forall i$ .Is there any analytical method?Thank you.

@SandeepTiwari I don't understand what is the problem. Show that the vector is orthogonal to itself, and then it will be zero. In particular you will get that $\alpha_i=0$.

@Mark Got it.thank you.

Once you have
$$\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ix_i,x_j\right\rangle=0$$
for each $1\le j\le n$, use linearity to obtain
$$\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ix_i,\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_jx_j\right\rangle=0$$
and therefore
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ix_i=0$$
Hope this helps. :)
